# How to reopen `construction` and `recruitment` popup message in Rome Total War?

Tags: rome-total-war

At the beginning of each turn, on the left hand, there are popup boxes which contain messages - important ones to me is the `construction` and `recruitment` ones.

Those boxes disappear when I load a saved game.

So my need is to reshow the boxes or more important, to restore the list of finised building and/or recruited army.

How would I do that in the game?

Comment: I believe they are check now or forever hold your peace. They get a bit insulted when you close out without reading them.

Comment: @Emerica. No one get instulted here dude. At beginning of your turn, save the game then load immediately - all pop boxes gone. I am insulted there then :)

Comment: I have been wondering this for years.

Comment: They likely appear when you start your turn, and ONLY when you start your turn. If you load a game, you're not "starting" a turn, and thus the boxes don't appear. I doubt what you're asking is possible.

Comment: @Izzy Why should it be on `start your turn` only? There's many many events occur at the turn and the need to reopen the event list is normal, e.g. I want to see the list of new finish buildings, what's wrong with that need :) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a "feature" of the series. You can't get them back if you re-load the game. Medieval 2 has the same problem, and it's bugged me as well.

You just have to check all the event reports before you save.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been mentioned, those reports only show up at the beginning of your turn.

Instead of saving at the beginning of your turn, save at the end (ie right before hitting the End Turn button). Thus when you reload your game, your first action is to click End Turn, and then you'll get your reports.

Comment: Though bear in mind that any conflicts will be re-rolled, so you may get slightly different results on a reload.